# How do I attach filenames with extensions in Rails 6 ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using ActiveStorage in Rails 6. I am clear with the concept of `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached`.
From that I had few questions:

1. Is possible to upload original filename with extension to storage instead of key?
2. How to specify storage path during has_many_attached. i.e I have 5 files that need to stored under object specific folder.
   e.g `/path/to/images/<image_id>/`

Answer (score 0):

The key is a secure token that points from your application's blob to the right file stored on the service (S3, etc.). Although you can't use something instead of the key, it is entirely possible to store the original (or any other) file/path when you attach. For example, given an instance of a class that `has_many_attachments :images`:

```rb
message.images.attach(io: File.open('/wherever/thing1.png'), 
                      filename: '/path/to/images/thing1.png', 
                      content_type: 'image/png')
```

The `filename` and `content_type` are stored with the blob, and can be used when querying:

```rb
message.images.blobs.find_by(filename: '/path/to/images/thing1.png')
=> #<ActiveStorage::Blob id: 1, key: "...", filename: "/path/to/images/thing1.png" ...>
```

So, if you have five files under a specific folder you would simply open/upload them and specify the appropriate `:filename` when you attach.

Comment: Is it not possible to change how rails stores the actual file?